# What does 'fidelity' of accessor keywords mean?

Tags: c#, encapsulation, accessor

I'm reading through .Net Docs and i came across this term "fidelity",

> Type safety is also used to help enforce encapsulation by guaranteeing
>   the fidelity of the accessor keywords.

What does it mean (in relation to accessor keywords)?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the page where the term "fidelity" appears ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/tour#type-safety

Comment: From what I can tell, the term "accessor" is incorrect here... it should be "accessibility" or "visibility", referring to the keywords `public` etc. because it's talking about what *other code* can call. I think that contributes to the confusion. Beyond that, it's unclear... perhaps it's referring to the consistency and validity of the state of an object and preventing arbitrary changes to the object by consumers. This is only a "tour" document, though, so don't get hung up on high-level descriptions.

Comment: The number of mistakes in that document is *large*. Holy goodness. I found half a dozen in just a couple of paragraphs.

Comment: @EricLippert - I'm glad you said that. I thought I was going crazy just looking at that slice of it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sigh.

There is simply too much documentation and not enough time for the development team to review it for accuracy in jargon. This overview is a *mess* of small errors and confusing, non-standard jargon usages.

The paragraph in question is:

> Type safety is also used to help enforce encapsulation by guaranteeing the fidelity of the accessor keywords. Accessor keywords are artifacts which control access to members of a given type by other code. These are usually used for various kinds of data within a type that are used to manage its behavior.

Yuck.  So much wrong here. "accessor keyword" should be "accessibility level".  "Other code" is confusing; "other code" means code which is *other* than *what* exactly? Accessibility modifiers control access to members *everywhere*, not just in "other code". Why are we talking about *members* and then suddenly switching to *data*?  What does "manage behaviour" mean?

Let's rephrase using standard C# jargon.

> **Static type checking** helps enforce encapsulation by ensuring that a program respects the **accessibility levels** declared by a member of a type. For example, if type `Dog` has a private member `mother`, then static type checking helps ensure that attempts to access that member from code outside the `Dog` class will be prevented.

Fixing all the rest of the crazy mistakes in this document is left as an exercise to the reader. For example, what's wrong with this code sample?

```
Dog dog = AnimalShelter.AdoptDog(); // Returns a Dog type.
Pet pet = (Pet)dog; // Dog derives from Pet.
pet.ActCute();
Car car = (Car)dog; // Will throw - no relationship between Car and Dog.
object temp = (object)dog; // Legal - a Dog is an object.
```

Comment: I entered a github issue with MORE RANTING. https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/13466

Comment: `Car car = (Car)dog;` : Well, if you insist on allowing `Car` to be allowed to inherit from `Dog`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoTFN.jpg

Comment: @EricLippert - so much is wrong with that code sample.  For starters Car car = (Car) dog; won't throw a runtime exception... it just won't compile.

Comment: On second though, there could be one way that it does compile, but implementing it would be basically useless and very misleading and dangerous.  However, that goes to the point that the documentation is just wrong on many levels.  If a developer implemented a static explicit conversion operator.

public static explicit operator Car(Dog d) => (Car) null;

Comment: But then it would not throw!

Comment: It compiles and throws if, say, car is an interface and dog is unsealed.

Comment: @EricLippert - True, thanks for clarifying.  I was only thinking of ways that the code sample is just bad, incomplete, and misleading.

Comment: It's too bad that as of today, the documentation still contains that misleading description ...